# Getting the file size of a file in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to write a file back to the client using a custom handler in ASP.Net and wondering what it the best way to do this with the least processing time. At the moment I have 2 different versions of the code that do the same thing, but because the handler will be used a lot, I'm wondering what the most efficient way is.

Load the complete file to a byte array and use `BinaryWrite` to write the file:

```
string filePath = context.Server.MapPath(context.Request.Url.LocalPath);
Byte[] swfFile = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
context.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", Utils.MakeString(swfFile.Length));
context.Response.ContentType = Utils.GetMimeType(Path.GetExtension(filePath));
context.Response.BinaryWrite(swfFile);
```

Using a `FileInfo` object to determine the file length and `TransmitFile` to write the file:

```
string filePath = context.Server.MapPath(context.Request.Url.LocalPath);
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
context.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", Utils.MakeString(fileInfo.Length));
context.Response.ContentType = Utils.GetMimeType(Path.GetExtension(filePath));
context.Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
```

I would suspect the `TransmitFile` method is the most efficient because it writes without buffering the file. What about the `FileInfo` object? How does it calculate the file size? And is a `FileInfo` object the best way to do this or is there an better way?

Comment: I think that you try a simple method for this. Use something like FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName); long s = f.Length;

Comment: `FileInfo` just asks the filesystem (usually considered "expensive" because it hits the disk); it's "the best" way to get the size. But the first approach keeps the whole file in memory for as long as the client takes to download it -- this can potentially be a **huge** problem.

Comment: You can pretty much discount the cost of using FileInfo to find the length of the file if you are going to read the file anyway (either directly or indirectly) - either way, the directory entries for the file are going to be read, and they will stay in the OS's file cache for a bit, so multiple physical reads for getting the file size are not going to happen.

Comment: In my opinion it's silly that the [`HttpResponse.TransmitFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy.aspx) documentation doesn't mention whether it will take care of notifying the client of the message boundary (i.e. set a `Content-length` header, perform chunking, closing the connection after transmitting). I would not expect having to explilcitly set the `Content-length` header in combination with such a method call, but I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: @CodeCaster Sadly it does not add the `Content-length` by itself. I guess that is cause it transmits as it reads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FileInfo` asks the filesystem for the file size information (it does not need to read all of the contents to do so of course). This is usually considered an "expensive" operation (in comparison to manipulating stuff in memory and calling methods) because it hits the disk.

However, while it's true that cutting down on disk accesses is a good thing, when you are preparing to read the full contents of a file anyway this won't make a difference in the grand scheme of things. So the performance of `FileInfo` itself is what you should be focusing on.

The #1 performance issue here is that the first approach *keeps the whole file in memory for as long as the client takes to download it* -- this can be a **huge** problem, as (depending on the size of the files and the throughput of the client connection) it has the potential of massively increasing the memory usage of your application. And if this increased memory usage leads to swapping (i.e. hitting the disk) performance will instantly tank.

So what you should do is use `TransmitFile` -- not because it's faster when going to the disk (it may or may not be), but because it uses less memory.

Comment: You may want to note that `FileInfo.Length` is an IO operation but does not need to "measure" the file size by reading all bytes, i assume that OP's question aims this issue(_"How does it calculate the file size?"_).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I thought that "asks the filesystem" hints to that, but I added an explicit mention anyway. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: +1 Asking the filesystem could also mean that the file-system answers after it has read all bytes ;) I think asking for `FileInfo.Length` is the same action that happens when you right-click a file and look at the size-on-disk property. It justs reads what was stored when the file was last modified.

Comment: @Jon: interesting read! I was wondering if the `FileInfo` is the best performing method to check the actual filesize (not the logical filesize) on disk? btw my use case is all server-side and no browser/client is involved.